# python Need help placing 'eg' after every vowel in a sentence

Tags: python

I am in the making of a new menu of i am currently developing and i am in need of some assistance. 
When the end user inputs his/her sentence the output is meant to show 'eg' after every vowel.

```
Example
Input: a girl skipped
output: aeg giegrl
```

My code:

```
def pigsl():
  print()
  print("You said the following:")
  time.sleep(1)
  sentenc = input("Please enter your sentence: ")
  print(sentenc)
  print()
  print("Your new sentence is:")
  senten = news(sentenc)
  time.sleep(1)
  print(senten)
  again()

def news(c):
    new = c
    vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
    for x in c.lower():
        if x in vowels:
            new = new.replace(x, "eg")
    return new
```

I understand it is replacing the vowel and then displaying 'eg'. Any method to avoid such replacement of the vowel ?

Comment: `new.replace(x, "%seg"%x)` must solve your problem. But you'd better use regexp

Comment: Any idea other then using regexp? I rather not go down that path even if it is a simple fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close with your attempt actually:

```
import time

def pigsl():
    print()
    print("You said the following:")
    time.sleep(1)
    sentenc = input("Please enter your sentence: ")
    print(sentenc)
    print()
    print("Your new sentence is:")
    senten = news(sentenc)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(senten)

def news(c):
    new=''                         #instead of new=c, just start with an empty string        
    vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
    for x in c:                    #iterate through the sentence
        if x in vowels:            #if the character is a vowel
            new+=(x+'eg')          #append the vowel + 'eg' to the new empty string
        else:                      #otherwise
            new+=x                 #just append the consonant to the new string
    return new

pigsl()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I new i was close but just could not get the code to work the way i wanted it to haha. I understand now, thank you again! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Pythonic way to do this:

```
line = "a girl skipped"

vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')

res = [x + "eg" if x in vowels else x for x in line.lower()]

print("".join(res))
```

> Prints: aeg giegrl skiegppeegd

The same version, less pythonic:

```
def convert(string):
   res = []
   for x in line.lower():
      res += x + "eg" if x in vowels else x 

   return "".join(res)


print(convert(line))
```

And basic iteration:

```
def convert(string):
   res = []
   for x in line.lower():
      if x in vowels:
        res += x + "eg"
      else:
        res += x

   return "".join(res)


print(convert(line))
```

Pay attention that I use `res = []` instead of `res = ""`. Two version will work the same, but working with lists [] is more efficient in this case, because string is immutable and every change will cause python to copy and generate new string object.

Comment: Is there another way other than a pythonic solution? 
Something less pythonic like what i had in my corrupt code. Thanks.

Comment: The basic iteration was totally something i was looking for the first time, i am not really the whole pythonic type of guy even if at times the pythonic way is more easier than the normal basic any day program but basic suits me big time. But Cheers for all these! Appreciate the effort you put into these:)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> def addeg(match):
...   return match.group(0) + 'eg'
... 
>>> re.sub('[aeiou]', addeg, 'a girl skipped')
'aeg giegrl skiegppeegd'
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAICT, your code was almost correct:

```
def news(c):
    new = ""                           # Start with an empty string
    vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
    for x in c.lower():
        new += x                       # Append each character as encountered
        if x in vowels:
            new += "eg"                # Append "eg" only if it was a vowel
    return new
```

---

And for my own not-so-pythonic way of doing:

```
def news(c):
    mapping = dict(a='aeg', e='eeg', i='ieg', o='oeg', u='ueg')

    return "".join(mapping.get(x,x) for x in c)
```

Comment: haha: a='aeg', e='eeg', i='ieg', o='oeg', u='ueg'. Very cleaver and totally not a way i would of thought on doing. Nice technique there ;) I love all this feedback! Totally enhances my knowledge for future projects/edits.